# Is there a modified Cartesian product that accounts for order?

Tags: functions, set-theory, order-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a bijective function. The graph $G(f)$ is given by a subset of the Cartesian product $X\times Y$.

Now, given the ordering relation $\preceq_X$ on $X$, it is possible to specify an order "induced by $f$" on $Y$ according to...

$$f(x)\preceq_Y f(y)\iff x\preceq_X y$$

If we index both sets by $I$ such that...

$$\forall i,j\in I.z_i\preceq_Z z_j\iff i\leq j$$

...then, under the above orderings...

$$G(f)=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{(x_i,y_i)\}$$

Seeing as this most closely resembles an 'entrywise product of sets', I would that there were a binary operation $\ast$, such that for any two totally ordered sets $A$ and $B$ where $|A|=|B|$...

$$A\ast B=\left\{(a_i,b_i)\in A\times B\mid i\in I\right\}$$

...given the appropriate indexing set $I$.

The generalization to partially ordered sets and non-bijective functions isn't particularly difficult, but it is tedious enough so as not to be included here.

In any case, the result of such a product is the graph of a function from $A$ to $B$. Such an operation seems beneficial, and at the very least provides a neat use for order relations, so I wonder if the operation already exists.

I mean, this has to be a thing, right?

Comment: The whole thing seems very convoluted to me. Since $f$ is a bijection (otherwise what does it mean to index both $X$ and $Y$ by the same $I$, and if that just means that $I$ is large enough to cover both and we allow repetition, we just fall back to $f$ being surjective), take $I=X$ and $\leq$ as $\preceq_X$. Then you just want to say that $A*B=f$. I don't know what is simpler than talking about $f$ that you need to come up with all these things...

Comment: @AsafKaragila The question arose in an algebraic/analytic context. The set of all [surjective] functions from $X$ to $Y$ is given by the product $X^Y=\prod_{x\in X}Y$. Objects within $X^Y$ are distinguishable by the ordering of components - e.g. $\forall f,g\in X^Y.f=g\iff \forall x\in X. f_x=g_x$. I hypothesize that there is a one-to-one correspondence between bijective $f\in X^Y$ and total orderings of $Y$. This is an attempt to make that correspondence explicit and examine it more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are *finite*, then you're defining the (graph of the) **unique order isomorphism between $A$ and $B$**. I don't think it has a common short symbolic *notation*.

"Graph of the" is usually omitted because in set theory we're usually identifying a function with its graph anyway.

If $A$ and $B$ are *not* finite then there can be many order isomorphisms between them -- there are many order isomorphisms between $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ and $\mathbb Q\cap[2,3]$, for example.

Similarly, if you have *partial* orders rather than total orders, then there can be multiple order isomorphisms even for finite set, and you would need a way to specify which of them you're talking about. For example if you have
$$ A=\{1,3,5,15\} \qquad B=\{2,4,6,12\} $$
both with the "is a divisor of" relation as an order, then you could either map $3\mapsto 6, 5\mapsto 4$ or map $3\mapsto 4, 5\mapsto 6$, and have an order-preserving map in each of these cases.

Comment: I see. Methinks I should have asked whether every unique function corresponds to a unique order isomorphism between $A$ and $B$. I wanted to treat this as an operation on 'the space of ordered sets' because it makes it easier to talk about how order relations effect different properties of functions, and how functions relate to order.

Comment: Oh, and you can assume that $A$ and $B$ are always infinte :)